# Как в 1с написать запрос который удалит первый символ из определённого поля?

Tags: 1с

Есть просто запрос на выборку данных из определённого поля, требуется составить запрос на обновление этого поля, так чтобы в поле сохранилось исходное значение без первого символа. Как написать запрос?

Запрос на выборку данных выглядит так:

```
Выбрать Подстрока(Штрихкод,1,4) ИЗ РегистрСведений.ШтрихкодыНоменклатуры где штрихкод подобно "046%"
```

Comment: в 1С запросы всегда только на чтение данных; Для изменения данных используйте код на языке 1С

Comment: Покажите структура регистра "ШтрихкодыНоменклатуры"

Answer (score 0):

Запросом обновить данные не получится. Он только для выборки данных служит.
Обновить значение Измерения/Ресурса можно, но кодом.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]